# ASP.NET MVC3 Remote Validation does not output error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I have a simple Model that is the default `RegisterModel` and upon creating a View based on that model for `Create` I end up having

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Remote("UserNameExists", "Account", "", ErrorMessage = "Username is already taken.")]
    [Display(Name = "Username (spaces will be stripped, must be at least 6 characters long)")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Editable(true)]
    [Display(Name = "First and Last name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "You need to enter a valid email")]
    [Remote("EmailExists", "Account", "", ErrorMessage = "Email is already taken.")]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    //[ValidatePasswordLength]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Create a password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Verify password")]
    //[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password's do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

and in the View:

```
<h3>
    Details</h3>
@using (Html.BeginForm("GenerateBetaLink", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "beta-user" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create Beta User" class="btn-submit" />
            <span class="loading"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

My `Validation Controller`

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult UserNameExists(string UserName)
    {
        OnlineServicesRepository db = new OnlineServicesRepository();

        var user = db.FindUserByUsername(UserName.Trim());
        return user == null ?
            Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) :
            Json(string.Format("{0} is not available.", UserName),
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult EmailExists(string Email)
    {
        OnlineServicesRepository db = new OnlineServicesRepository();

        var user = db.FindUserByEmail(Email.Trim());
        return user != null ?
            Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) :
            Json(string.Format("{0} is not available.", Email),
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**My problem is** that Remote Validation does fire, but **does not write** anything into the **Error Message** as it should, plus, the jQuery method `.valid()` **keeps telling me** that the **form is valid**:

[image]
<sub>(source: [balexandre.com](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2011-04-19_0900.png))</sub>

> **What am I missing** here?

The [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/gg508808(v=vs.98)) shows the same code (in the downloadable file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following worked fine for me:

Model:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "You need to enter a valid email")]
    [Remote("EmailExists", "Home", "")]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(RegisterModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult EmailExists(string email)
    {
        if ((email ?? string.Empty).Contains("foo"))
        {
            return Json(email + " is not available", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model RegisterModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: Dang, I don't get mine to work at all :( my `ValidationMessageFor` is there but it's never been populated ... there is no javascript errors that I can see in the console, it's just ... no idea (and yes, I do have the validate.js and unobtrusive.js files in my view if you wonder) :/

Comment: @balexandre, how does your controller action look like?

Comment: just added into the question, but works fine as it's passing the correct values as you can see in the FireBug console ... I just create a simple View with just the email and I still dont get the validation message to work :(

Comment: @balexandre, that's very weird as I am unable to reproduce this behavior. It works for me. If you send me a narrowed down version of the project illustrating the problem by email I would be happy taking a look at it to see what might be the problem. Oh an one thing to checkout is whether the version of jquery you are using is compatible with the version of the jquery.validate plugin you are using. IIRC there were some issues with jquery 1.5 and older versions of the validate plugin.

Comment: @Darin using jQuery 1.5.2 and validation 1.8. Try this link to see a Screencast of what I'm doing: http://gape.cc/epvHrC

Comment: @balexandre, I've just watched the screencast. Sweet :-) Unfortunately it doesn't bring more information than what you have already provided in the question and I am still unable to repro :-)

Comment: @Darin ... though I though I was using validation 1.8, the true was that it was still 1.7 (default) - I overrided this in other projects, but somhow forgot this one, after overriding the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.min.js` to the latest version, the messages started to work

Comment: @Darin JING is lovely for the this screencasts :) very easy to create them and I love to share. One again, Thank you for the MVC help, your **check version** made light into my head :)

Comment: @balexandre, great I am glad I could have pointed you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it by updating to the latest jQuery (1.6) and jQuery.validate (1.8) libraries.  The easiest way to get these is searching NuGet for jQuery.